# FPU Anamoly In NASM

Tags: nasm

I'm performing a program which seeks sum of square of floating point numbers provided in array

I've initialized `ST1` and `ST` to `+0.0` by using `FLDZ` twice and loaded the first Number Pointed by `RSI` to `ST` and multiplied by itself and added the result to `ST1` and ran the above procedure through a loop

The array is `array dd 15.0,7.0,9.0`

The block which performs given operation is

```
        mov rsi,array
        fldz
        fldz
        xor rcx,rcx
        mov cl,3
    variance:
        fld dword[rsi]
        fmul dword[rsi]
        fadd st1
        add rsi,4
        loop variance
        fld st1
        call display
        mov rax,60
        syscall
```

Consider `display` as a procedure which prints Floating Point Numbers stored in `ST`

Expected Output : 355.0000
Actual Output : 274.0000

Comment: After the loop the final result (355) resides in `ST0`. Then you load `ST1` (274)  to `ST0` and display it. You are consuming 6 FPU registers (ST0-ST5). I suspect you're not aware of the organization of a FPU stack. Please work through a tutorial on the FPU again.

Comment: @rkhb Oh!Thanks I never noticed that.Anyway I replaced `FLD` by `FADD` and made a few more modification which worked for me.